# Solving for Initial Velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity, projectile

A ball is dropped from the building 150 m high at the same instant a second ball is thrown upward from the ground. If the two balls pass each other at a point 60 m above the ground, solve the initial velocity of the second ball.

(I'm quite confused, like is the information provided above enough to solve for the initial velocity? Plus tips how you solved it (if ever you did)))

Answer (score 1):

I believe this may a useful approach.  $x_{1}$ refers to the vertical position of ball 1 (starting at the top of the building) and $x_{2}$ is ball 2.  $h$ is the height of the building.

$$
x_{1}=h-\frac{1}{2}gt^{2}  \quad \left(1\right)
$$

$$
x_{2}=v_{0}t-\frac{1}{2}gt^{2}  \quad \left(2\right)
$$

Solve for the time when ball 1 reaches 60 m above the ground (dropped from top of building) using equation 1.

$$
60=150-\frac{1}{2}gt^{2}
$$

$$
\frac{1}{2}gt^{2}=150-60=90
$$

$$
t^{2}=\frac{180}{g} \implies t=\sqrt{\frac{180}{g}}
$$

Now, find the initial velocity of ball 2 using equation 2, substituting in for $t$:

$$
60=v_{0}\left(\sqrt{\frac{180}{g}}\right)-\frac{1}{2}g \frac{180}{g}
$$

$$
60=v_{0}\left(\sqrt{\frac{180}{g}}\right)-90
$$

$$
150=v_{0}\left(\sqrt{\frac{180}{g}}\right)
$$

$$
150 \left(\sqrt{\frac{g}{180}}\right) =v_{0}
$$

I hope this helps.